# last seen time stamp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I got a message at 16:05pm, then my contact went offline again, but the last seen was showing 15:25, how is it that it hasnt changed to 16:05 when the contact left whatsapp and still showed the earlier time of 15:25,

It is now working correctly when the contact sends me a text the last seen time updates every time correctly.

Please help,

confused gary

Comment: I'm guessing your contact is in a timezone that is one hour behind you.

Comment: Apart from that, it's not really an *Android* question – but rather something specific to *WhatsApp* in general. You might better ask in some WA support forum.

Comment: Yup, it's a question for the WhatsApp peeps...

Comment: Sorry but they live 30 minutes away from me

Comment: Ok, well, I would go over to the WhatsApp boards and ask them.  We can't really diagnose a problem with a third-party app like that - if you're 100% sure that your contact is not in another timezone or connected to a network that resides in another timezone, then it's a bug in the software that should be reported.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, will try the whatsapp Forums.